# Laravel 5.2 ErrorException instead of Warning

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5

Given `invalid argument supplied for foreach()`, can anybody explain to me why Laravel gives `ErrorException` instead of `Warning`?

In regular PHP I would just ignore that warning and proceed coding. Whereas in Laravel I'd have to do some other actions to pass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel converts PHP errors to Exceptions:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php#L56

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any convention to deal with this, like using `try {} catch {}` or is it okay if I just turn if off?

Comment: The best practice is to fix errors. For runtime exceptions, either `try {} catch {}`  them, or validate parameters beforehand to avoid exceptions.